Cloudflare + Next.js Image is loading blurry image when small
I seem to have a problem where all of the images that are being rendered small, are blurry and very grainy. I've tried setting quality to 100 but it still doesn't change anything. I am using Next.js Image for these.
Here is my "ImageTile" component. I toss this component in any size grid and it will auto scale to take the width of the grid. This image is showing up blurry
 import Image from "next/image"

 <div className='z-10 hover:cursor-pointer relative'>
        <Image
            className="object-cover object-center w-full max-w-full h-40 rounded-lg"
            src={url}
            alt=""
            width={500}
            height={500}
        />
 </div>

Output:

Here is my loader function that pulls from cloudfront:
'use client'

export default function myImageLoader({ src, width, quality }) {
    return process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION + `${src}?format=auto&quality=${quality || 75}&width=${width}`
}

I've tried fill={true}, changing the width and height to larger values.
Here is my next.config.js:
    /**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
    serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["mongoose"],
  },
  images: {
    loader: 'custom',
    unoptimized: false,
    loaderFile: './components/images/Loader.jsx',
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'lh3.googleusercontent.com',
        pathname: '**',
      }
    ],
  },
  webpack(config) {
    config.experiments = {
      ...config.experiments,
      topLevelAwait: true,
    }
    return config
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig

